# ApexChart Treechart Ajax $.getJSON, get the full node

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery and apexcharts. I would like to get the data from a json url, but i don't know the correct way to make it work, i have to render the name and the data from a json, sorry for the basic question. Thanks in advance.

This is the working function:

```
<script>
  var options = {
    series: [
     {
      "name":"Criptomoedas",
      "data":[
         {
            "x":"ADA",
            "y":"11000.0"
         }
      ]
     },
     {
      "name":"Fundos Imobiliários",
      "data":[
         {
            "x":"HGLG11",
            "y":"30000.0"
         }
      ]
     }
   ],

    chart: {
     height: 350,
     type: 'treemap',
     toolbar: {
     show: false}
    }
  };

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();

</script>

<div id="chart"><div>
```

Here is the codepen i have commented the new code that i am trying to make work:
https://codepen.io/diogo-wernik/pen/PomrBpG

than i have created a json file identical the series:
https://run.mocky.io/v3/f6951d2e-a85d-4409-b9d8-f21767af74cf

```
[
   {
      "name":"Criptomoedas",
      "data":[
         {
            "x":"ADA",
            "y":"11000.0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Fundos Imobiliários",
      "data":[
         {
            "x":"HGLG11",
            "y":"30000.0"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Now i want to use getJSON, to load the series, i tried that, but dont understand how to get the full node and update the series:

```
<script>
  var options = {
    series: [],

    chart: {
     height: 350,
     type: 'treemap',
     toolbar: {
     show: false}
    }
  };

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();

var url = 'https://run.mocky.io/v3/f6951d2e-a85d-4409-b9d8-f21767af74cf';

$.getJSON(url, function(response) {
  chart.updateSeries([{
    data: response
  }])
});
</script>

<div id="chart"><div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was very simple. Didn`t need to have  ([{data: response}]), only (response)

```
var url = "https://run.mocky.io/v3/f6951d2e-a85d-4409-b9d8-f21767af74cf";
$.getJSON(url, function (response) {
 chart.updateSeries(response);
});
```

Here is the function working on fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgc0xdsm/